# yii, how to avoid savings in submitbutton form

Tags: php, yii

i want to avoid the saving on database whenever the data thats being stored on the field is the same as is being on db (to avoid duplications), in yii, i use the form made by gii, im making a renderpartial on another view, so you might see the code in a view action, its totally normal, here are the codes.

controller/action(view)

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $dec=new DecretoCaracterizacion;

        if(isset($_POST['DecretoCaracterizacion']))
        {
            $error='error';
            $model=DecretoCaracterizacion::model()->findAll();
            $dec->attributes=$_POST['DecretoCaracterizacion'];
            if(in_array($_POST['DecretoCaracterizacion']['decreto_id'] , $model))
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$id, 'error'=>$error));
            elseif($dec->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id'=>$id));
        }


        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id), 'dec'=>$dec
        ));
    }
```

form renderpatial for DecretoCaracterizacion

```
<?php
/* @var $this EquipoController */
/* @var $car Equipo */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'decretocaracterizacion-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Campos con <span class="required">*</span> son requeridos.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($dec); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($dec,'decreto_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($dec,'decreto_id',CHtml::listData(Decreto::model()->findAll(),'id','ndecreto'), array('empty'=>'Seleccione decreto', 'value'=>'0')); ?> <p class="note">Valor por defecto "0"</p>
        <?php echo $form->error($dec,'decreto_id'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($dec,'caracterizacion_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($dec, 'caracterizacion_id', array('readOnly'=>'true', 'value'=>$car->id)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($dec,'caracterizacion_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($dec->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

what i want here, i dont want the decreto_id to be duplicated, even if i see its not being duplicated, i see in DB thats being duplicated but dont know why its not shown in the view.

update: theres one caracterizacion that can have many decretos, but cant have same decretos in 1 caracterizacion.

model

```
<?php
    /*$decre = array();
    foreach($model->decreto_caracterizacion as $val) {
      $decre[] = $val->decreto_id;
    }
/**
 * This is the model class for table "caracterizacion".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'caracterizacion':
 * @property string $id
 * @property string $parametro
 * @property integer $decreto_id
 */
class Caracterizacion extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'caracterizacion';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('parametro', 'required'),
            array('decreto_id', 'length', 'max'=>256),
            array('parametro', 'length', 'max'=>256),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, parametro', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
        'decreto'=>array(self::MANY_MANY,'decreto','decreto_caracterizacion(caracterizacion_id,decreto_id)'),
        'peticion'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Peticion','peticion_id'),

        );

    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'parametro' => 'Parametro',
            'decreto_id' => 'Decreto',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('parametro',$this->parametro,true);
        $criteria->compare('decreto_id',$this->decreto_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Caracterizacion the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

        public function columna($variable)
    {
        $sql="alter table parametro add ".$variable." boolean";
        $data=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
        return $data;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unique validation rule in Model

Answer (score 0):

you can always check anything that you think would be wrong an return `false`and stop the process in any step of the saving rout!

I would prefer to use [`beforeValidate()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#beforeValidate-detail) and check for existing records with some of the columns that are exactly the same,

also you can make custom [validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/)

Example:

```
public function beforeValidare()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition('....'); // add conditions to meet your requirements

    if(MyModel::model()->exists($criteria)) // check if records with those conditions exists
        return false; // do this to break the chain

    return parent::beforeValidate(); // don't forget this line
}
```

Comment: would you send me or type an example?.. im new at this

Comment: i guess my condition would be decreto_id, caracterizacion_id?. remember, 1 caracterizacion can have many decretos, also there can be another caracterizacion that can have almost the same decretos. if that so, it would be (decreto_id, caracterizacion_id) right?